# How to compress years 2001a-n in author-date biblatex style?

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chicago

Is it possible to configure biblatex-chicago to compress a case like
"Karasti et al. 2016a, 2016b, 2016c, 2016d" into "Karasti et al. 2016a-d"?  If yes, how?

All the four entries have the same author/year combinations but are actually different publications.

If necessary, am happy to provide MWE.

Comment: Please provide an MWE, yes :)

Comment: Please do provide an MWE. Your question is reasonably clear without one, but it gives us a good place to start and makes sure that we are all talking about the same thing. It should be possible, but it can be really messy with `biblatex-chicago`. Since you would not comply with Chicago style with these changes anyway, would it be possible to use one of the standard styles (`style=authoryear-comp`)?

Answer (score 5):

As it turns out this is a bit more complicated than I initially thought. It is possible to sort this out for the standard style `authoryear-comp` as shown below, but I'm a bit more sceptical about `biblatex-chicago`.

> Since version 0.5 [`biblatex-ext`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ext) includes the styles `ext-authoryear-ecomp` and `ext-authoryear-iecomp` with native compression of `extradate` lists based on the code presented here. See commit [e1c4116 on GitHub](https://github.com/moewew/biblatex-ext/commit/e1c41160be3eca3e978bd7a6231d2b7b088d3c93).
>
> ```
> \documentclass[british]{article}
> \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
> \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
> \usepackage{babel}
> \usepackage{csquotes}
>
> \usepackage[style=ext-authoryear-ecomp, backend=biber]{biblatex}
> \addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
>
> \usepackage{hyperref}
>
>
> \begin{document}
> \cite{sigfridsson}
>
> \cite{knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c,knuth:ct:d,knuth:ct:e}
>
> \printbibliography
> \end{document}
> ```

The solution is similar to what `numeric-comp` does. The main problem is that `biblatex` normally does not know what the next entry is because the items in a list of citations are handled one-by-one with little knowledge of the overall list. So it is not entirely trivial to process a list of citations and decide whether or not to skip over a particular citation because it happens to be the *b* in *a-c*.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{cbx@extradatecount}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:init}{%
  \ifnumless{\value{multicitecount}}{2}
    {\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}%
     \global\undef\cbx@lastkey
     \global\undef\cbx@lasthash
     \global\undef\cbx@lastyear
     \global\undef\cbx@lastextradate
     \setcounter{cbx@extradatecount}{0}}
    {\iffieldundef{prenote}
       {}
       {\global\undef\cbx@lastkey
        \global\undef\cbx@lasthash
        \global\undef\cbx@lastyear
        \global\undef\cbx@lastextradate
        \setcounter{cbx@extradatecount}{0}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:reinit}{%
  \global\undef\cbx@lastkey
  \global\undef\cbx@lasthash
  \global\undef\cbx@lastyear
  \global\undef\cbx@lastextradate
  \setcounter{cbx@extradatecount}{0}}

\newcommand*{\extradateonlycompcitedelim}{\addcomma}
\newcommand*{\extradateonlycompciterangedelim}{\bibrangedash}


\newbibmacro*{generic:dump:extradate}{%
  \ifundef\cbx@lastkey
    {}
    {\entrydata{\cbx@lastkey}
       {\ifnumless{\value{cbx@extradatecount}}{1}
          {\blx@warning{% This should not happen, so warn when it does
             Uh-oh!
             The extradate compression is quite likely\MessageBreak
             wrong for \cbx@lastkey}}%
          {}%
        \ifnumgreater{\value{cbx@extradatecount}}{1}
          {\setunit{\extradateonlycompciterangedelim}}
          {\setunit{\extradateonlycompcitedelim}}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:extradate}}%
     \setunit{\cbx@thiscitedelim}}%
  \global\undef\cbx@lastkey
  \setcounter{cbx@extradatecount}{0}%
}

\newbibmacro*{cite:dump:extradate}{%
  \def\cbx@thiscitedelim{\multicitedelim}%
  \usebibmacro{generic:dump:extradate}}

\newbibmacro*{textcite:dump:extradate}{%
  \def\cbx@thiscitedelim{%
    \ifbool{cbx:parens}
      {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
      {}%
    \textcitedelim}%
  \usebibmacro{generic:dump:extradate}}

\newbibmacro*{cite:comp:extradate}{%
  \ifnumequal{\cbx@lastextradate+1}{\thefield{extradate}}
    {\stepcounter{cbx@extradatecount}%
     \savefield{entrykey}{\cbx@lastkey}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:dump:extradate}%
     \setunit{\extradateonlycompcitedelim}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:extradate}}%
  \savefield{extradate}{\cbx@lastextradate}%
}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:dump:extradate}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:reinit}}
       {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
          {\ifthenelse{\iffieldequals{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}\AND
                       \(\value{multicitecount}=0\OR\iffieldundef{postnote}\)}
             {\usebibmacro{cite:comp:extradate}}
             {\usebibmacro{cite:dump:extradate}%
              \setunit{\compcitedelim}%
              \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}%
              \savefield{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}%
              \savefield{extradate}{\cbx@lastextradate}%
              \setcounter{cbx@extradatecount}{0}}}}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:dump:extradate}%
           \printnames{labelname}%
           \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}%
           \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}%
           \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}%
           \savefield{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}%
           \savefield{extradate}{\cbx@lastextradate}%
           \setcounter{cbx@extradatecount}{0}}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:dump:extradate}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:reinit}}%
  \setunit{\multicitedelim}}

\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%
  \iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
       {\ifthenelse{\iffieldequals{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}\AND
                    \(\value{multicitecount}=0\OR\iffieldundef{postnote}\)}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:comp:extradate}}
          {\usebibmacro{textcite:dump:extradate}%
           \setunit{\compcitedelim}%
           \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}%
           \savefield{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}%
           \savefield{extradate}{\cbx@lastextradate}%
           \setcounter{cbx@extradatecount}{0}}}
       {\usebibmacro{textcite:dump:extradate}%
        \setunit{\compcitedelim}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}%
        \global\undef\cbx@lastyear}}
    {\usebibmacro{textcite:dump:extradate}%
     \ifnameundef{labelname}
       {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
           \setunit{%
             \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
             \printdelim{nonameyeardelim}\bibopenparen}%
           \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
             {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
             {}%
           \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
       {\printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit{%
          \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
          \printdelim{nameyeardelim}\bibopenparen}%
        \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
          {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
          {}%
        \iffieldundef{shorthand}
          {\iffieldundef{labelyear}
             {\usebibmacro{cite:label}}
             {\usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}%
           \savefield{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}%
           \savefield{extradate}{\cbx@lastextradate}%
           \setcounter{cbx@extradatecount}{0}}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}%
           \global\undef\cbx@lastyear}}%
     \stepcounter{textcitecount}%
     \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}%
  \setunit{%
    \ifbool{cbx:parens}
      {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
      {}%
    \textcitedelim}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump:extradate}%
   \usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand*{\cite}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{citeyear}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump:extradate}%
   \usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump:extradate}%
   \usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand*{\parencite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{citeyear}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump:extradate}%
   \usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump:extradate}%
   \usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcitetext}[\mkbibfootnotetext]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump:extradate}%
   \usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\smartcite}[\iffootnote\mkbibparens\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump:extradate}%
   \usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cbx@textcite}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{textcite}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{textcite:dump:extradate}%
   \usebibmacro{textcite:postnote}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson}

\cite{knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c,knuth:ct:d,knuth:ct:e}

\cite{knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c,knuth:ct:d}

\cite{knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c,knuth:ct:e}

\cite{knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:d,knuth:ct:e}

\cite{knuth:ct:c,knuth:ct:d,knuth:ct:e}

\cite{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c}


\cite{aksin,knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c,knuth:ct:d,knuth:ct:e,sigfridsson}

\cite{aksin,knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c,knuth:ct:d,sigfridsson}

\cite{aksin,knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c,knuth:ct:e,sigfridsson}

\cite{aksin,knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:d,knuth:ct:e,sigfridsson}

\cite{aksin,knuth:ct:c,knuth:ct:d,knuth:ct:e,sigfridsson}

\cite{aksin,knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c,sigfridsson}

\textcite{sigfridsson}

\textcite{knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c,knuth:ct:d,knuth:ct:e}

\textcite{knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c,knuth:ct:d}

\textcite{knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c,knuth:ct:e}

\textcite{knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:d,knuth:ct:e}

\textcite{knuth:ct:c,knuth:ct:d,knuth:ct:e}

\textcite{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c}


\textcite{aksin,knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c,knuth:ct:d,knuth:ct:e,sigfridsson}

\textcite{aksin,knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c,knuth:ct:d,sigfridsson}

\textcite{aksin,knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c,knuth:ct:e,sigfridsson}

\textcite{aksin,knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:d,knuth:ct:e,sigfridsson}

\textcite{aksin,knuth:ct:c,knuth:ct:d,knuth:ct:e,sigfridsson}

\textcite{aksin,knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c,sigfridsson}

\textcite{aksin,knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c,knuth:ct:d,knuth:ct:e,sigfridsson,worman}

\textcite{aksin,knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c,knuth:ct:d,sigfridsson,worman}

\textcite{aksin,knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c,knuth:ct:e,sigfridsson,worman}

\textcite{aksin,knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:d,knuth:ct:e,sigfridsson,worman}

\textcite{aksin,knuth:ct:c,knuth:ct:d,knuth:ct:e,sigfridsson,worman}

\textcite{aksin,knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c,sigfridsson,worman}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would not even want to get started doing that for `biblatex-chicago`. The style is much more complicated than the already tricky `authoryear-comp`.
`biblatex-chicago`'s citation code for dates is longer than the entire `authoryear-comp.cbx` and the code for `cite` and `textcite` is again roughly as long. Additionally, the citation format of the CMS does not even omit the years for citations from the same year and the `origyear` handling makes that complicated on a conceptual level as well.